# Uploaded image width

Tags: 7, media

After uploading an image, it is re-sized to a width of 904 pixels; I need to keep the original file (1080 pixels).

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you using a an image field or some other functionality or module?

Comment: It could also be necessary to know the image related settings.

Comment: allowed extensions png, gif, jpg, jpeg
image field
min and max dimensions 1080x270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagecache (drupal 6) and Image Style (drupal 7) modules copy your image from your base files directory (default is "sites/default/files") and place the resized image an a folder based off of the name of your style (thumbnail would be "sites/default/files/imagecache/thumbnail").

Both modules don't remove the original image from the base files folder. They just create a copy. So your original file that is 1600 pixels should be a available in your base files folder.

"example_image.jpg" uploaded to example.com using Drupal 6, would be found in:
http://example.com/sites/default/files/example_image.jpg (original)
http://example.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/thumbnail/example_image.jpg (created by imageache using "thumbnail" preset).

Comment: I'm using and image field with max and min resolution of 1080x270, and this is not happening the image on the base files (sites/default/files) after upload is 904

Comment: Gotcha. Is there a reason you can't increase the imagefield max and min and then use imagecache / image styles to control the size of the output? That way you would keep your original image.

Answer (score 1):

It was my problem: I took the original dimensions wrong, then Drupal resized the original image to fit the max dimensions.